# how to use opt.setHeaders in koa-send?

Tags: node.js, koa, koa2

The document said "You should only use the setHeaders option when you wish to edit the Cache-Control or Last-Modified headers, because doing it before is useless (it's overwritten by send), and doing it after is too late because the headers are already sent.".
but why it will be overwritten by res.send? can anyone give a example?

Comment: It sounds like the package you are using explicitly sets those headers. So if anything was set before, those values will simply be overridden.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.